# iOS app crashes crashes occasionally - Upon screen display or scroll down

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management, crash

My iOS app crashes upon a certain screen. That happens occasionally.

The app crashes sometimes upon the appearance of the screen, or sometimes when we scroll down the screen. Here is the crash report:

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xe0000010
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3958af2a _objc_release + 10
1   CoreFoundation                      0x31637441 __CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 17
2   Foundation                          0x31f5c01d -[NSAutoreleasePool release] + 121
3   UIKit                               0x335437e1 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 225
4   UIKit                               0x334ff803 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 259
5   QuartzCore                          0x332a9d8b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 215
6   QuartzCore                          0x332a9929 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 461
7   QuartzCore                          0x332aa85d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 17
8   QuartzCore                          0x332aa243 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 239
9   QuartzCore                          0x332aa051 CA::Transaction::commit() + 317
10  QuartzCore                          0x332e10f7 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 255
11  QuartzCore                          0x332e0ff1 CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) + 65
12  IOMobileFramebuffer                 0x35538fd7 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 155
13  IOKit                               0x322db449 _IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 193
14  CoreFoundation                      0x316be5db __CFMachPortPerform + 119
15  CoreFoundation                      0x316c9173 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
16  CoreFoundation                      0x316c9117 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 139
17  CoreFoundation                      0x316c7f99 __CFRunLoopRun + 1385
18  CoreFoundation                      0x3163aebd _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
19  CoreFoundation                      0x3163ad49 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
20  GraphicsServices                    0x351ed2eb _GSEventRunModal + 75
21  UIKit                               0x33550301 _UIApplicationMain + 1121
22  Numerology                          0x00021313 main (main.m:13)
```

I have tried to go through the code to find possible sources of exception, but I am not able to trace the exception.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: i think you are releasing already realesd objects

Comment: what is your code? you use scrollview or Tableview?

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD I'm using a TableView...

Comment: show your custom cell code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SIGSEGV is a segmentation fault, meaning you are trying to access an invalid memory address.

SIGSEGV literally means you're accessing an address you don't own. So it's not necessarily that you're accessing a released object; you could be accessing an object that never existed, as in:

```
UIView *myView; // uninitialised, may point to anything
[myView setFrame:someFrame];
```

Or even just making an error in C-level non-object stuff, such as:

```
int array[100];
array[1000] = 23; // out-of-bounds access
```

So please double check you code carefully. May be you find that error.

Comment: Null reference exception was happening. Thanks